# applet don't load on firefox

Tags: java, html, firefox, applet

Hello I am trying to load applet on web browser. I have create html and include applet tag

```
<applet code="com.asprise.imaging.scan.ui.demo.PanelMain.class"   
 codebase="."archive="asprise-imaging-ui.jar,asprise-imaging-
 scan-core.jar" width="400" height="300">
```

I have jar file also in same folder where i created my html,it gives me error.

> This plug-in is not supported

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: there's a missing space between `codebase` "." value and `archive`. `codebase="."archive="asprise-imaging-ui.jar,asprise-imaging-
 scan-core.jar"`

Comment: The W3C specification does not encourage the use of <applet> and prefers the use of the <object> tag. Under the strict definition of HTML 4.01, this element is deprecated and entirely obsolete in HTML5. from [Mozilla homepage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/applet)

Comment: will applet execute using <object> tag ?

Comment: why don't you make the applet runnable jar and then sign it and use in html code, If u need i can post the complete procedure

Comment: @GeorgeRosario sure. please post complete procedure

Comment: hello @GeorgeRosario i am going to edit my question with stack track please check it.

Comment: Can u please a add the plugins. It may there but blocked. or it may be downloaded, if blocked allow that or else google how to add java plugins

Comment: *"applet don't load on firefox"*  Which (other) browsers have you seen it work on?  If 'none' then this is likely not specific to FF (therefore don't mention it).  Otherwise list the other browsers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse select the main applet file right click and export it to **runnable jar**. Let all the dependent jar's bundled.
Then in command prompt browse to the folder your jar is placed and type the following commands.

```
1.keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias m4key  //m4key unique key
2.keytool -export -alias m4key -file bmcert.crt   //bmcert.crt certificate name
3.jar tvf Jarname.jar verify jar // jarname.jar is the jar file created
4.jarsigner Jarname.jar m4key
5.jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs JarnameJarname.jar
```

Then simply use the html script and in **code property** specify the main file of Applet.

```
<html>
<applet width="1100" height="600" archive="EnrollmentApplet.jar" code="com/vaazu/biometric/Applet/EnrollmentApplet.class"></applet>             
</html>
```

If you are using **java8** ,the security issue by Java 8, Which is not allowing now to display or load the self signed Applets on browser. Please **open configure java** in settings and in security TAB put the URL of the html page which is using applet in Exception Site List

[image]

Comment: i have no source code.. i have only two jar files asprise-imaging-core.jar and asprise-imaging-ui.jar.

Comment: i have no source code..  
i have only two jar files asprise-imaging-core.jar and asprise-imaging-ui.jar
i have create one bat file which content "java -cp asprise-imaging-core.jar -jar asprise-imaging-ui.jar
pause "
 When I double click on bat file it execute applet (in windows OS) now same things i want to run same thing in web browser

for that i have create one html file with <applet code="com.asprise.imaging.scan.ui.demo.PanelMain.class" code base="."archive="asprise-imaging-ui.jar,asprise-imaging-scan-core.jar" width="400" height="300"> 
  
  </applet> 
but it not execute in web browser.

Comment: Leave the batch file , just use the applets  jar and sign it and use.

Comment: i will check and let u know in within one hours . stay tune :)

Comment: @JavaMan we are here to help :)

Comment: when i fire  keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias m4key in command prompt it ask me password so which password i should enter

Comment: enter any secure key , But remember it.

Comment: hello @George i have edit Question with stack trace please check

Comment: applet run succesfully but give me exception 'Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://192.168.0.223:6060/scan/asprise-imaging-ui.jar' then what is the cause behind this? can you help me?

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml refer this link, I think now the Answer could be accepted as Right.

Comment: this can be solved by adding the Applet in Exceptions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78490/discussion-between-java-man-and-george-rosario).

Comment: how can i add applet in exception ??

Comment: <html>
 <body>
  <applet code="com.asprise.imaging.scan.ui.demo.PanelMain.class" code base="."archive="asprise-imaging-ui.jar,asprise-imaging-scan-core.jar" width="400" height="300"> 
  
  </applet>
 </body>
</html>

This is my html will you please tell me ?